# When are Entity instances automatically attached to a context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've read a few questions and texts on attachment but they seem to skip some detail on how it works. For example, I don't know why the following happens:

```
MyContext c  = new MyContext();
MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
/* some local edits in e  */
c.MyEntity.Add(e); // Works fine
```

But if I edit it inside a function on another class(which does not create a new instance), I get IEntityChangeTracker exception:

```
MyContext c  = new MyContext();
MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
e = ViewModelClass.SomeFunctionWhichAltersAnExistingEntityInstance(e);
c.MyEntity.Add(e); //IEntityChangeTracker "multiple instances" exception
```

Most answers on this subject say that this happens when an object is attached to multiple contexts.

If this is whats happening, when and why an instance of an entity class becomes automatically attached to a context(and where does this context come from)?

About the Entity version used:
  RuntimeVersion:v4.0.30319
  Version:5.0.0.0

Comment: Are you setting the Primary Key property in your method?

Comment: @GeorgeVovos No. It is an identity (1,1)

Comment: Are you setting a Navigational property inside the method?Is the code inside the method the same as  /* some local edits in e  */  ? Show us the Method if you can

Comment: @GeorgeVovos thats it. There was "e.myentity2 = ViewModel.myentity2" (where ViewModel.myentity2 was queried previsouly from the database) which didn't exist in the local edits. When I added that line to the original function it also threw the exception. This line might not be even necessary, but could you explain me the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you saw, the problem is that your Navigational properties are from another context(They are tracked by another context). 
These Objects are tracked by another context.
When you call the Add method EF not only adds that object as Added but also all its Navigational properties/Associations

You can
1)Pass the context as a parameter to your method and use that context to create/read the objects that you set as Navigational Properties

2)Use .AsNoTracking() when you create your related properties from the other context.
 **Be very careful,in this case calling the add method with mark the entire object graph as Added.   This means that EF will add duplicate records for each navigatinal property.

You will have to set each Navigational Property's State property to 'Unmodified' (using the context's Entry method )after you call Add.

For more info check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx**